# Find the cost, given that reducing the selling price from 1080 to 1026 increased the loss by 4%

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

> When a shopkeeper reduces the selling price of an article from 1080 to
>   1026 his loss increases by 4% . What is the cost price of article?

Solution of book : 
4% CP =  1080-1026

CP = 1350

Easy enough. Now see very similar question (came in exam):

> If a man reduces the selling price of a fan from rs 1250 to Rs 1000,
>   his loss increases by 20%. The cost price of the fan is

Answer Options :

1. 2400
2. 2450
3. 2500
4. 2350

Now if we apply method which we had applied on first question , you wouldn't find your answer in one of the options even! . So let's try diff method

CP - 1250 = 5x //eq no. 1 //here 5x is total loss amount, since the old and new loss amounts are in the ratio 5:6

CP - 1000 = 6x //eq no. 2

solving above two equations will produce x = 250 , put it in to eq no.1 , and CP = 2500, and we got solution.

Now if you apply just above method on to the first question you'll again find the diff answer oO

So please explain which method is correct and where is discrepancy occurring from.

**Edit (trying to refute both answers)** :

> CP - SP(old) = x% of CP //eq 1
>
> CP - SP(new) = y% of CP //eq 2
>
> SP(old) - SP(new) = (y-x)% of CP //eq 2-1

Concrete example :

let's CP = 100, and SP = 80 , hence loss = 20% of CP
now let's change SP = 70, hence loss = 30% of CP

now let's use `SP(old) - SP(new) = (y-x)% of CP`

`80-70 = 10% of CP`

which gets `CP =100` back

Hence above method shouldn't be wrong, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, the first method is not correct.

the word "loss" ought to refer to the difference between the cost price ($C$) and the sell price ($S$). For clarity, let's define $S$ to be the initial sell price, prior to any discounts. (So for the first problem $S=1080$ and for the second $S=1250$) Then, for the first one I'd write:

$$.04(S-C)=-1080+1026=-54\;\Rightarrow\;S-C=-1350$$ $$C=S+1350=1080+1350=2430$$

The second method follows this procedure

Comment: Please have a look at edited part of question.

Comment: But the problem doesn't say "the loss changed by a specified percent of the Cost."  If it did, then the method would be correct.  The way the problem reads it says "the loss changed by a specified percent of itself"

Comment: aaah now you cleared my confusion :) Thanks :)

Comment: Please help me with question , similar to above: A man sold an article at a gain of 5%. Had he sold it for Rs 40 more, he would have gained 8%. Then the cost price of the article is?

Comment: My answer is coming 4000/3, but actual answer is 10000 :( . Thanks

Comment: I can't get 10,000 by any reading. The question is ambiguous.  I read it the same way you do:  Letting $c$ be the cost price.  Then I think we both read it as $1.08c=4000+1.05c$. I could also see reading it as $1.13c=4000+1.05c$ but neither approach gives $10,000$.

Comment: yeah , seems the question maker was retarded at the time of creation of question, and this question came in govt exam paper :\ . Anyways thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Going exactly by the questions framed,
answer to the first one is *wrong*, and that to the second one is *right.*

For the *answer* to the first to be right, the *question* needs to be:

"When a shopkeeper reduces the selling price of a article from 1080 to 1026,
 his loss increases by 4% **of C.P.** . What is the cost price of article?